# Redirection from domian.com to www.domain.com?

Tags: magento, redirect

Can anyone help in learning how to redirect `domian.com` to `www.domain.com` (I use Magento) step by step?

Preferably give some screenshots how to do all that.

Also, please let me know how to redirect permanently the category to product page in Magento.

I tried many times doing it on my own seeing some instructions in Google, but really did not help. So, I would like somebody specifically helping me in that.

Comment: Did you set secure and unsecure base url with www ?

Answer (score 0):

Hello add below code into your .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Hope this help you

Comment: Thank you so much Vishal for this response. Since I'm not a tehie guy, I don't know where is that .htaccess file? Can you please tell me where exactly can I go in my website backpanel to paste this code? I use magento.

Comment: MagikVikash, one more thing. If I change that from domain.com to www.domain.com, will all the pages in my website be automatically be redirected to www.?

For Example: http://domain.com/product/furniture to http://www.domain.com/product/furniture

Comment: Hello yes its redirected to www. your backpanel check show hidden files otherwise you create .htaccess & add above code

Comment: I Thank again for your so fast reply. Are you on skype?

If yes, please add me syedusman80.

You were so helpful in all. Since I just started all this, I'm getting now clue how to create .htaccess.

But, I got cleared my doubt that all the pages will automatically be redirected, if the above code is pasted in the .htaccess file.

Comment: Hello check your cpanel ->public html or www -> magento root folder -> check hidden file.if not create .htacces file such as file name is .htaccess